# Python Splinter (SeleniumHQ) how to take a screenshot of many webpages? [Connection refused]

Tags: python, urllib2, selenium-webdriver

I want to take a screenshot of many webpages, I wrote this:

```
from splinter.browser import Browser
import urllib2
from urllib2 import URLError

urls = ['http://ubuntu.com/', 'http://xubuntu.org/']


try :
    browser = Browser('firefox')
    for i in range(0, len(urls)) :
        browser.visit(urls[i])
        if browser.status_code.is_success() :
            browser.driver.save_screenshot('your_screenshot' + str(i) + '.png')
        browser.quit()
except SystemError :
    print('install firefox!')
except urllib2.URLError, e:
    print(e)
    print('theres no such website')
except Exception, e :
    print(e)
    browser.quit()
```

and I got this error:

```
<urlopen error [Errno 111] Connection refused>
```

How to fix it?:)

**EDIT**

When I have links in txt file, the code below doesnt work:

```
from splinter import Browser
import socket

urls = []
numbers = []

with open("urls.txt", 'r') as filename :
    for line in filename :
        line = line.strip()
        words = line.split("\t")
        numbers.append(str(words[0]))
        urls.append(str(words[1].rstrip()))

print(urls)

browser = None    
try:
    browser = Browser('firefox')
    for i, url in enumerate(urls, start=1):
        try:
            browser.visit(url)
            if browser.status_code.is_success():
                browser.driver.save_screenshot('your_screenshot_%03d.png' % i)
        except socket.gaierror, e:
            print "URL not found: %s" % url
finally:
    if browser is not None:
        browser.quit()
```

My txt file looks like this:

```
1   http//ubuntu.com/
2   http//xubuntu.org/
3   http//kubuntu.org/
```

when I ran it, I got errors:

```
$ python test.py 
['http//ubuntu.com/', 'http//xubuntu.org/', 'http//kubuntu.org/']
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 21, in <module>
    browser.visit(url)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/splinter/driver/webdriver/__init__.py", line 79, in visit
    self.driver.get(url)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 168, in get
    self.execute(Command.GET, {'url': url})
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 156, in execute
    self.error_handler.check_response(response)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/errorhandler.py", line 147, in check_response
    raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: u'Component returned failure code: 0x804b000a (NS_ERROR_MALFORMED_URI) [nsIIOService.newURI]'
```

whats wrong this time?

Comment: First step - just try to open the page "normally" using a browser, and see if that works...

Comment: @JonClements: it works when I have only one link but when I have more, I get this error :(

Comment: Yes, try to open `http//ubuntu.com/` and pray. `NS_ERROR_MALFORMED_URI` explicitly means URL is not correct.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your problem is you do `browser.quit()` inside of your loop through the URLs, so it is no longer open for the second URL.

Here's an updated version of your code:

```
from splinter import Browser
import socket

urls = ['http://ubuntu.com/', 'http://xubuntu.org/']

browser = None    
try:
    browser = Browser('firefox')
    for i, url in enumerate(urls, start=1):
        try:
            browser.visit(url)
            if browser.status_code.is_success():
                browser.driver.save_screenshot('your_screenshot_%03d.png' % i)
        except socket.gaierror, e:
            print "URL not found: %s" % url
finally:
    if browser is not None:
        browser.quit()
```

The major change is moving the `browser.quit()` code into your main exception handler's `finally`, so that it'll happen no matter what goes wrong. Note also the use of `enumerate` to provide both the iterator value and its index; this is the recommend approach in Python over maintaining your own index pointer.

I'm not sure if it's relevant for your code, but I found `splinter` raised `socket.gaierror` exceptions over `urllib2.URLError`, so I showed how you could trap them as well. I moved this exception handler inside of the loop; this will continue to grab the remaining screenshots even if one or more of the URLs are non-existent.

Comment: thank You so much (I have to test it first) but I think thats exactly what I need! Thaaaanks :*

Comment: I have some problems with this code:( Could you be so kind and take a look at my edit? I pasted a new version, where I have links in *.txt file but it doesnt want to work :/

Comment: Generally, it's recommended that you start a new question to focus on the new problem.

Comment: You've left the colon out of your URLs this time.

Comment: Argh, those little dots :P Thanks, that was the issue - now it works perfectly :D