# Is there a possibility to add a progress bar to splinters browser code?

Tags: python, progress-bar, selenium-webdriver, splinter

I have a code which downloads lots of webpages (it takes a screenshoots of them, to be clear). Is there any way to add to my application a progress bar? I use `wx`, but I would like to know if there is a progress bar in a splinter (seleniumHQ) library and how to use it.

You can see my code here: [Python Splinter (SeleniumHQ) how to take a screenshot of many webpages? [Connection refused]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12660625/python-splinter-seleniumhq-how-to-take-a-screenshoot-of-many-webpages-connec) it's without wx but on my computer I have a version with wx panel. Any ideas?

Comment: I'm not 100% sure, but you might be out of luck in terms of a progress bar for percentage of page loaded, as that would require the browser to provide a call back (and then if it's having to run Javascript to generate it, how does it now how much more until it's complete?) and some way for Selenium to access that. The closest you'll probably get is just a progress bar akin to page 1/5 loaded... etc...

Comment: @JonClements: yup, that was it I did it that way: `waitDialog = wx.ProgressDialog(title='Screenshooter', message=u'Please wait ...', maximum = len(self.urls)) || # splinters stuff ` and then, in a for loop I have: `waitDialog.Update(i+1)` pretty nice idea, thanks :)